# How to remove the selected checkboxes from Modal in Angular2 and display it in the page and vice versa

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have a Add button in my page on click of which a modal appears with a list of checkboxes.User has an option to select the checkbox options.
The modal has Save and Cancel button.When I click on Save button with some of the checkboxes selected , I want the selected checkboxes to be removed from the modal and appear on the page with Remove option aside after the modal closes.And when I click on Remove link in the page, the checkboxes should get added to the modal again by being unchecked.
Right now, the selected checkboxes are getting removed from the modal but that is not appearing on the page with my code.

I have made a component for the modal where the code for populating checkboxes is-

```
<div class="modal-body">
<tr *ngFor= "let names of org.employees">
<td>
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="names.checked" name="{{names.firstName}}"></md-checkbox>
</td>
</tr>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="save" (click)="saveModal()">SAVE</button>
<button class="close" (click)="closeModal()">CLOSE</button>
</div>
```

In .ts file-

```
saveModal(){
(this.org)=this.modifyOnCheck(this.org);
this.showModal=false;
}

modifyOnCheck(emp_json:any){
var newEmpJson=emp_json;
for (var i in emp_json.employees){
if(emp_json.employees[i].checked){
(emp_json.employees[i].splice(i,1);
newEmpJson=this.modifyOnCheck(emp_json);
}
}
return newEmpJson;
}
```